# Cross validation after logistic regression and cross-validation of optimal cut points

Tags: logistic, cross-validation

I have modeled a logistic regression and **I have been asked to cross-validate my results.**
I have used the cvauroc function in stata. My independent variable of interest is compromisedlung (p = 0.000 in the regression). 
[image]

How to interpret the output? Is the cvMean AUC = 0.84 reason enough to state that the model is accurate and reasonably validated?

Furthermore, I have been asked to provide optimal cutpoint and for compromisedlung and to **cross-validate the cutpoint as well.**  In particular, I was asked to set two different cutpoints, one with high sensitivity and the other with high specificity and to cross-validate them. 
Although I was able to find an optimal cutpoint using the cutpt function, I do not know what should I do next.

[image]

However, I do not know how I can cross-validate such a cut point in Stata and what output am I looking for.

What should I do ?

Thanks in advance for your precious help